# Gravatar default image cache issue on localhost

Tags: asp.net, html, caching, browser-cache, gravatar

I have a very strange problem with gravatar.

I have a public default image on `example.com/image.jpg`

I have changed this image on the public website quite a while ago (more than a week ago).

Since then, on `localhost`, when i am developing the website i still see the old default image, however when i publish the website on the remote domain, the default image shows up as the correct one, the new one.

I have cleared my browser cache numerous times and tried it on all major browsers.

Anyone have a clue why this is happening?

This is how i am creating the url

```
 string defaultImg = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode("http://example.com/image.jpg");
 string URL = string.Format("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{0}?r=pg&s={1}&d={2}",hash,size,defaultImg);
```

And then request for avatar

```
private bool makeAvatarRequest(string URL)
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                displayImage(responseStream);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And display image

```
private void displayImage(Stream stream)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        MemoryStream temp = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(temp, ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] buffer = temp.GetBuffer();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        img.Dispose();
        temp.Dispose();
    }
```